# Why isn't "Verbing" always allowed?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, neologisms

Why are *varnish* (*varnish the truth*),*gloss* (*glossed over her faults*), and *paint* (*paints him more innocent than the evidence suggests*) used metaphorically, but not *lacquer*?

Comment: [Gloss](https://www.lexico.com/definition/gloss) as in 'glossed over her faults" is only tangentially related to gloss paint. The word is older than gloss paint and has several other meanings, including 'interpretation'.

Comment: Also 'varnish' and 'paint' are Middle English words whereas 'lacquer' is 16C at the earliest and 'lacquer' is much less commonly used. 'Varnishing the truth' and 'painting him as more innocent' were probably well established before 'lacquer' came into the language and didn't need augmenting.

Comment: I have heard "get lacquered" in casual British usage to mean "get drunk".

Comment: "Gloss" (n. meaning lustre or v. meaning to give a shine to) is related to Old Norse *glossi* (blaze) and *glōa* (to glow). That word is not related to "gloss" meaning "interpretation", which comes from Greek *glossa/glotta*, from which we also get "glossary" and the -glot words.

Comment: Also in US slang a "shellacking" is a beating. Shellac is a type of lacquer

Comment: Let's not forget a thin veneer of respectability.

Comment: What would the effect of lacquering be?  When would you want to use it metaphorically? Wikipedia says it's done to produce a hard, durable finish. So could you lacquer the truth? Lacquer over her faults? Or lacquer him more innocent than the evidence suggests? :-) Maybe James Dean enthusiasts in the 1950's were described as having lacquered hair, but it's not a very good metaphor: Brylcreem's probably mostly lacquer *anyway*.

Comment: Perhaps Tchaikovsky lacquered over the end of his 1812 overture when he added the cannons and bells. A hard and durable finish.

Comment: Perhaps a difference is that painting is a quick and easy way of covering something up (giving something "a lick of paint" is an archetypically quick and easy thing), while lacquering is a complex highly technical process. Also, the fact that most people are familiar with the process of painting but less so with lacquering makes painting better as a metaphor.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian - laquering can conceal; lacquers can be smooth, durable and opaque.

Comment: _Acrylic_ seems largely unverbed at the moment.  And _crayoning_ largely unmetaphored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lacquer as a metaphor is rare, but not unknown. Often found as a part of a phrasal verb - 'lacquer over', to conceal or hide beneath a respectable-looking outer layer.

> We found that the strategies themselves reveal underlying cultural
> and religious differences that should not be lacquered over. From the
> Cambridge English Corpus.

[Lacquered (examples) Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lacquered)

> A lie wrapped in a fabrication, lacquered over with a falsehood

[Blog](https://www.thedailyparker.com/post/2018/03/06/a-lie-wrapped-in-a-fabrication-lacquered-over-with-a-falsehood)

> Leadership is arrogant, sexist and bullying. Show the least sign of
> concern or empathy for a customer and you will be crushed. It's churn
> and burn, the people that succeed and rise to the top are ego maniacs
> who don't care in the slightest about anyone but themselves. The worst
> thing is, this is all lacquered over with the most cringe making
> 'appreciation events' that mean nothing. You could be at one in April,
> and fired in May. Really abusive place that promotes based on totally
> unintelligible criteria, hasn't got a clue about leadership and is
> ritually abusive.

[Employee review on Glassdoor](https://www.glassdoor.co.uk/Reviews/Employee-Review-Gartner-RVW10390649.htm)

Comment: I think your answer sufficiently answers my question. Thanks, Michael Harvey!